# Могу ли я использовать стороннюю внешнюю библиотеку во VUE 3, не предназначенную для VUE?

Tags: vue3

Всем добрый день! Я новичок.

Могу ли я использовать стороннюю внешнюю JS библиотеку во VUE, не предназначенную для VUE ? Например, я хочу использовать библиотеку dropzone. Выполняю команду `npm i dropzone`, `подключаю:import dropzone from 'dropzone';import 'dropzone/dist/dropzone.css';` .

Смотрю документацию из библиотеки, по сути, помещая эту форму в шаблон, она уже должна работать:  `<template> <form action="/target" class="dropzone" id="my-great-dropzone"></form> </template>`. Но она не работает!

Знаю, что есть Vue-dropzone, но интересует работа именно с теми JS библиотеками, которых нет во VUE3! Как работать с ними?